# Python Flask app not displaying pdf file container I made in html file

Tags: python, html, flask, pdf

I have a html file with below code which is displays an embed pdf file on webpage. while running the app.py, webpage is displaying just fine but pdf is not displayed. I tried adding file to static folder as well but didn't work. can someone help me out here? Thanks!

**HTML** markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>display pdf on webpage</title>

   <!--This will align our textboxes and labels-->
    <style type="text/css">
                label{
                    width: 100px;
                    display:inline-block;}>

        .container{padding: 30px;}
    </style>
    <style>
        body
        {
        background-image: url({{url_for('static',filename='bg_image.jpg')}});
          background-attachment: fixed;
          background-size: cover;
          }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<!--Title-->
<h2 align="center">Title</h2>
<h3 align="center" style="position:relative; bottom:15px;">Please select your Data </h3>

<!--Label and input-->
<label style="position:relative; left:5px; bottom:15px;"> Data 1:</label>
        <input name ="data1"  type="text" style="position:relative; bottom:15px;">
<label style="position:relative; left:10px; bottom:15px;"> Data 2:</label>
        <input name ="data 2" type="text" style="position:relative; bottom:15px;">
<label style="position:relative; left:10px; bottom:15px;"> date:</label>
        <input name ="date" type="date" style="position:relative; bottom:15px;">

<!--Buttons:-->
<input style="position:relative; bottom:15px; left:20px;" type="submit" value="Generate"/>
<input style="position:relative; bottom:15px; left:20px;" type="reset" value="reset" />
<p></p>

<!--pdf container-->
 <div
         class = "container" style="position:relative; bottom:20px">
        <embed src = "\location\filename.pdf" type="application/pdf" width = "100%" height = "590px" />
      
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def main():

    return render_template("html_code.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Why are you not using `url_for` for the pdf like you did for the jpg? What does the developer console say?

Comment: I just used url_for but it just doesn't display .pdf file

    <style>
        body
        {
        pdf: url({{url_for('static',filename='process_flow.pdf')}});
<!--          background-attachment: fixed;-->
<!--          background-size: cover;-->
          }
    </style>

-------------------
No errors though

Comment: did you find a solution